# Laravel - [PDOException] SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'ip.priorities' doesn't exist

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

Hello im trying to migrate a table named `ideas_roles_users` with Laravel 5.1 but im getting the error

> [PDOException] SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'ip.priorities' doesn't exist.

I'm really new with Laravel, hope anyone can help me. As you see im trying to make a table many to many and the error becomes from class `CreateIdeasRolesUsersTable`. Thank you.

```
<?

class CreateIdeasRolesUsersTable extends Migration

{
    public function up()
    {
Schema::create('ideas_roles_users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('id_ideas')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('id_roles')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('id_users')->unsigned();

            $table->primary(['id_ideas', 'id_roles', 'id_users']);


            $table->timestamps();

        });

        Schema::table('priorities', function($table) {
          $table->foreign('id_ideas')->references('id')->on('ideas');
          $table->foreign('id_roles')->references('id')->on('roles');
          $table->foreign('id_users')->references('id')->on('users');
       });


    }
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('ideas_roles_users');
    }
}
```

My class for Ideas

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateIdeasTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('ideas', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('nombre');
            $table->string('descripcion');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('ideas');
    }
}
```

my class for users

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('user');
            $table->string('nombre');
            $table->string('appellidoP');
            $table->string('appellidoM');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password', 60);
            $table->string('pais');
            $table->string('estado');
            $table->string('ciudad');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('users');
    }
}
```

My class for Roles is:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateRolesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('roles', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('nombre');
            $table->longText('descripcion');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('roles');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the error. The problem it was that I had `'Schema::table('priorities', function($table)'` and not `'Schema::table('ideas_roles_users', function($table)'` because my table name is 'ideas_roles_users'. My bad. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your code: `Schema::table('priorities', function($table)`. It should be `Schema::create()` not `Schema::table()` since you're trying to create a table. `Schema::table()` is commonly used if you want to modify a table.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your time to answer. I found the error and isn't was the "Schema::table" it was I had 'Schema::table('priorities', function($table)' and not 'Schema::table('ideas_roles_users', function($table)' because my table name is 'ideas_roles_users'. Thank you again.